# Having Stylised Lower and Upper Case in a TM Name - does it matter?

Tags: united-kingdom, trademark, trade-name

Am currently looking to register a music artist name as a Trade mark.
For example, if I was wishing to register a name like

RipTide (capital T)

as opposed to

Riptide  (lower case t)

...on the application, is it important that I use my preferred capital R and capital T version - RipTide - or will it be rejected if I do?

Many thanks!